# How do I query a table with conditions from related table with Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, conditional-statements, relationship

I have two tables,

table users:
id, name, etc

table videos:
id, user_id, etc

Model: Video

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

I want to select all videos where it is owned by the user "Max".

I have tried thing like the following:

```
$Videos = \App\Models\Video::with('user')->where('user.name','=','Max')->get();



Unknown column 'user.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `videos` where `videos`.`deleted_at` is null and `user`.`name` = Max)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's what `whereHas` is for:

```
$Videos = \App\Models\Video::with('user')->whereHas('user', function($q){
    $q->where('name','=','Max');
})->get();
```

Comment: The problem with has() and whereHas() is that it does a full table scan with a subquery. You're better of just doing a join manually.

Comment: @asdasd that is indeed the problem i faced when i did this on a table with 10 thousand raws. It will hang for big tables